# Only static members can be accessed in initilizers

Tags: function, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a new variable that gets the total price by multiplying quantity to price but it's giving me an error: Why can't i do this?

```
class OrderScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final item;
  final quantity;
  final price;
  OrderScreen({this.item,this.quantity,this.price});



  @override
  _OrderScreenState createState() => _OrderScreenState();
}

class _OrderScreenState extends State<OrderScreen> {
  var totalprice = widget.price * widget.quantity; //Only static members can be accessed in...



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do that in the initState

```
var totalprice;

@override
void initState(){
  totalprice = widget.price * widget.quantity;
}
```

static members are the only one that can be used to initiliaze other members (because they're created before the constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create `getter` also.

```
double get totalprice => widget.price * widget.quantity;
```